# My question is about Cayley graphs where the Cayley set is any set of transpositions.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I want to show that if $S$ is any subset of $Sym(n)$ such that $S$ contains only transpositions, then the Cayley graph $X=Cay(Sym(n), S)$ is bipartite.

I have figured out that the vertices in $X$ associated with transpositions are pair-wise non-adjacent due to the fact that every permutation is either even or odd and so multiplying two transpositions can't give as a result another transposition. So I think one of my bipartite sets will be the set of transpositions but I am not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be great.

Comment: ...and the other bipartite set will contain the products of two transpositions. But where do you put the products of three transpositions?

Comment: That is where I am stuck. Do you have any hints on where to go from here?

Comment: If I take an element that is made of n even transpositions and hit it on the left with a transposition, I will always get an odd element. Either left multiplying will give n-1 transpositions or n+1. Ok so on that line of thought, one of my bipartite sets will be even transpositions and the other will be odd transpositions. Am I on to something here?

Comment: yes, that seems to be a good idea.